# neovim - unable to setup gopls integration

Tags: neovim, lsp, filetype-go, lunarvim

I have configured my neovim editor using this link (https://github.com/LunarVim/Neovim-from-scratch).

I have run LspInstallInfo and installed gopls successfully here.  However, when I open type of file *.go, I do not get the builtin go language server support here.  Goto Definition, auto-complete etc, do not work at all.  Very minimal features such as showing suggestions from Buffer (due to previous usage of a word in in the file) work.

I run LspInfo, which gives the following output indicating that 0 client(s) attached.

```
Language client log: /Users/rvnath/.local/state/nvim/lsp.log
Detected filetype:   go

0 client(s) attached to this buffer:
Configured servers list: jsonls, sumneko_lua
```

Runing :checkhealth shows...

- OK: Go: `go version go1.18.3 darwin/amd64`

Running :LspInstallInfo shows...

```
  Installed    servers (5)
  - gopls (go)
    version v0.9.1
    latest  v0.9.1
    installed 04 Aug 2022 22:45
    install dir ~/.local/share/nvim/lsp_servers/gopls
    ...
```

In spite of all this, language binding is not happening.  Am I missing some other configuration like onAttach().  My expertise is not in this area of nvim configuration.  So, any help would be greatly appreciated.